# $[A, B] = 0 \Rightarrow E_\lambda(A) \cap E_\mu(B) = E_{\lambda\mu}(AB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$E_\lambda(A)$ stands for the eigenspace of an operator (say, a matrix) with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

It probably doesn't matter whether the antecedent stands for the commutator or a general Lie bracket, but is this true in general? Because I just encountered a case in my research in which it is. (Decomposing a representation space under the action of SU(3).)

If it's true we may have some fun with it, because there's maybe some categorical way of putting it. Say, the part of some functor in which the domain category has eigenspaces as objects and intersection as morphisms. And the codomain (do they call that target?) category also has eigenspaces as objects, but the morphisms are matrix multiplication.

Please tell me how I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. E.g. when $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$, $E_0(A)\cap E_1(B)$ is one-dimensional but $E_0(AB)$ is two-dimensional.

The above counterexample can be modified so that $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular. Consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1),\,B=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1)$ and $E_1(A)\cap E_{-1}(B)$ for instance. Briefly speaking, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda\mu$ in $AB$ can be greater than the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $A$ or the multiplicity of $\mu$ in $B$.

Comment: Interesting. Would you know of any *equivalent* conditions to the equality in question? (Theorems, propositions..)